# Отсутствие тире после наречия "вокруг"

Tags: тире

Оглянитесь, вокруг чудеса.

Возможен ли вариант написания без тире перед "чудеса"?

Answer (score 1):

Возможен.  Читаем в справочнике Розенталя:

> При отсутствии паузы в эллиптических предложениях тире не ставится: А
>   в доме стук, ходьба… (Гр.); Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая(Л.);
>   Скрип шагов вдоль улиц белых, огоньки вдали (Фет); У Хохла пожар!
>   (М.Г.); Револьвер на стол! (Тр.); Справа дверь в соседнюю комнату,
>   слева выход на террасу (так оформляются ремарки в пьесах); В этом вся
>   суть.

https://info.wikireading.ru/226910

У Вас эллиптическое предложение, произнесёте с паузой - поставите тире, произнесёте без паузы - тире не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры Розенталя из другого ответа вообще не соответствуют данному предложению. В них вообще нет связи между частями. А в вашем примере очень сильная смысловая часть между фрагментами.

Хорошо двоеточие поставить. Тут причина - зачем нужно оглянуться? какая причина? Потому что вокруг чудеса. В таких случаях ставится двоеточие.

Запятая здесь вообще не правильна. Тогда бы получилась простая констатация. А в данном предложении это крайне не логично. Запятая подходит тогда, когда части вообще не связаны:

`Иду в магазин, он читает книгу.`

Причина, по которой нельзя ставить запятую, в том, что в первой части призыв к действию, который далее разъясняется. Но теоретически можно с запятой, если чуть-чуть поменять:

`Оглядываюсь, вокруг чудеса.`

Comment: "Оглядываюсь, вокруг чудеса". Нет, так про чудеса не пишут, чудесами надо восхищаться. А у вас получается: Оглядываюсь, вокруг никого и ничего.

Comment: Ну естественно, я с вами согласен. Поэтому и написал, что теоретически. Если у автора сильная депрессия)))

Comment: Если депрессия, то да, тогда и чудеса не помогут.

Comment: Могут и помочь. Но уже в следующих предложениях в продолжении истории...

Answer (score 0):

Оглянитесь, вокруг чудеса.

Чудеса есть, а контекста нет. У этого  предложения неопределенная структура, его нужно редактировать, чтобы выбрать подходящий знак.

(1) ***Вы ищете чудеса? Оглянитесь — чудеса вокруг!***

(2) ***Вы ищете чудеса? Оглянитесь, чудеса вокруг вас.***

Это БСП, второе предложение эллиптического вида. Тире или запятая ставятся между простыми предложениями.

Выбор знака определяется по наличию паузы и по интонации. Отношения между частями БСП изъяснительные.

В первом варианте пауза ставится на месте сочетания ***и вы увидите.***  Во втором варианте второе предложение продолжает тему первого предложения, увеличенной паузы нет.